# fetching upto a limited condition in oracle query

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle10g

I need to alter the query below, to fetch the first 5 most recent users, instead of just the most recent single user.  But as sql do not allow `LIMIT` like it can be done in mysql, i have prepared this:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE joined in (select max(joined) from users)
```

This will fetch me most recent user but can not understand how i can extend it to 5 most recent users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SOmething like this must work for you:

```
      SELECT * FROM (select * from users order by joined DESC) u where rownum<=5
```

If you select from already ordered data, rownum, will correspond to the latest date.

Comment: Thanks, it is simple and sweet solution ^_^

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT m.* 
FROM (SELECT u.*
           , rank() OVER (ORDER BY u.joined) r 
      FROM users u) m 
WHERE r BETWEEN 0 AND 5 
ORDER BY m.joined
```

Comment: `RANK()` may get more than 5 (in case of ties). Also it is enough to check for `r <= 5` since it can't be less than 1.